# PowerShell WQL from different sources performance

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

Have the following WQL Queries, which work well.

```
$avg = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -computername $computername | 
               Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | 
               Foreach {$_.Average}

$tcat = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -computername $computername |
               Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*tomcat*"} |
               Sort-Object PercentProcessorTime -Descending |
               select -First 1

$mem = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computername |
               Foreach {"{0:N2}" -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize)}
```

been logging the results of these to a SQL database for over a week.

[image: Server list]

The first one has "overall" CPU usage of 70% and a process CPU of 98%.
Does this mean 98% percent of the 70% usage or 98% of the system CPU?

It is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Process_CPU column is populated by data from the "Percent Processor Time" field of WMI.  What "Percent Processor Time" measures is the amount of time that the processor spends on a non-idle thread (technically it counts the amount of time that the thread *is* idle, then subtracts that as a percentage from 100).

Since you're measuring Tomcat, I imagine you're measuring this on a webserver.  This is saying that 98% of the time, Tomcat is running in a non-idle capacity (meaning it's doing *something* like processing a request or serving the website).

To more specifically answer your question, rather than your PROCESS_CPU column measuring 98% of 70%, it's measuring a >0% usage 98% of the time.

Comment: Right..  So when you look at Task Manager, you see a percentage of CPU by process and is why `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process` and I know the `win32_processor` is overall..  I really need process as part of CPU.

Comment: If I am reading your response properly, Tomcat8 is taking up 68% of the whole CPU?

Comment: Your first column (CPU) is an average of the CPU that tomcat is using, so you would be safe saying that tomcat uses 70% of a CPU on average.  The second column could almost be considered "Tomcat uptime" since it's measuring the time it takes for the process to complete.  Tomcat never "completes" because it runs constantly, so a 98% "uptime" makes sense for that process.

Comment: One thing that may be giving you unexpected results @Leptonator is that WMI tends to bug out when >100% CPU utilization occurs.  Tomcat can use as many CPU's as you have on the machine, so if you have 4 CPU's Tomcat can theoretically use up to 400% CPU.  One better way to do this may be to use the "Get-Process" cmdlet and store the output in a CSV, then calculate average CPU usage from the CSV results.